# inter process comunication (IPC) in C

Tags: c, winapi

I am looking for an inter-process communication facility that can be used between languages on the same operating system(Windows7 for ex).I need to share some addresses(data) between two processes(one written in assembly ,other in C/C++).

Any help or resource?
Thanks.

Comment: So many to choose from - Corba, Named pipes, TCP/IP client server, shared memory, etc.

Comment: Take a look at ZeroMQ. http://zeromq.org It's a little easier than using plain ol' sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a messaging system, and not simply a way to share data.  For simple applications, you could define a **WM_USER+XXX** message, or use **RegisterWindowMessage**, that both applications agree upon.  You could also use **WM**_COPYDATA to this purpose.  If your apps do not have a Windows message queue (console apps, say), you would want to use the **Winsock** API, **named pipes** or some synchronization object, like an **event or semaphore**, to implement messaging (not recommended, as it would imply threading).

Answer (score 2):

It's called shared memory. On Windows, it's implemented via CreateFileMapping()/OpenFileMapping() and MapViewOfFile() API functions.